# Irreducibility of $x^2+y^2+z^2-xyz-2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Are there some general criteria for deciding the irreducibility of polynomials? For example the one in the title?

Comment: Your best bet is always Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @Ian: how do you use Eisenstein's criterion for the polynomial in the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this polynomial were to factor, it would have to factor into a polynomial of degree 2 and a polynomial of degree 1.
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xyz - 2
&= \big([\text{terms of degree } 2] + [\text{terms of degree } \le 1] \big) \\
&\quad \big([\text{terms of degree } 1] + [\text{terms of degree } \le 0] \big) \\
\end{align*}
The terms of degree $2$ in the first factor and the terms of degree $1$ in the second factor must multiply to $-xyz$.
By symmetry in $x,y,$ and $z$, we may assume they are therefore $-xy$ and $z$, respectively.
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xyz - 2= (-xy + ax + by + cz + d)(z + e)
$$
But there is no $x^2$ or $y^2$ term on the RHS, so this is impossible.

**General Method**

Some discussion of this in the case that the polynomial is irreducible over ANY field, can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97805/irreducibility-of-a-polynomial-in-several-variables-over-any-field).
There are also some tricks in the case of two variables [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables).

One possible approach is to consider any polynomial $p(x,y,z)$ (in general, any number of variables) as a polynomial in $x$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[y,z]$ (in general, $\mathbb{Z}$ could be any unique factorization domain).  Note that $\mathbb{Z}[y,z]$ is a unique factorization domain itself, so things like Gauss's lemma and Eisenstein apply.  In this case, we would have to have
$$
x^2 + (-yz) x + (y^2 + z^2 - 2) = (x + q_1(y,z))(x + q_2(y,z))
$$
for polynomials $q_1$ and $q_2$,
which reduces to the problem of showing $y^2 + z^2 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[y,z]$.  Then in turn we could consider $y^2 + z^2 - 2$ as a polynomial in $y$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[z]$, to get
$$
y^2 + z^2 - 2 = (y + r_1(z))(y + r_2(z))
$$
for polynomials $r_1$ and $r_2$ in one variable.
Then we have that $r_1(z) + r_2(z) = 0$, so $r_1(z) = -r_2(z)$,
so $z^2 - 2 = -r_1(z)^2$, so $2 - z^2$ is a perfect square.
So we have $2 - z^2 = (az + b)^2$, and we conclude $a^2 = -1$, $ab = 0$, and $b^2 = 2$.  This is of course impossible, not just over $\mathbb{Q}$ but over any field of characteristic $ \ne 2$.

Comment: Yep, that works. But it is not really a general criterion, though a similar Argument might apply in other examples as well.

Comment: @user39082 I've added some details and references which may be useful in the general case.